# How to share an array between forks?

Tags: c++, c, fork, shared-memory

I am writing this code, which basically takes an argument specifying how many child threads I want, forks to get them, and then prints all the pids which are stored in an array.

This would be fine if only the parent would need the PIDs, but I also need the child to get their IDS (pcid). I copy and pasted some code from the net (which I didn't really understand), so I'm not sure why it's not working.

I get a segmentation error after the first PID prints.

What's wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

if(argc  < 2) {
printf("ERROR: No arguments fed.\n");
exit(-1);
}

int amount = atoi(argv[1]);
int i;
int pid = 1;
int pcid = 0;
key_t key;
int shmid;
int *arr[amount];

key = ftok("thread1.c",'R');
shmid = shmget(key, 1024, 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

for(i = 0; i < amount; i++) 
{
    if(pid != 0) 
    {
        pid = fork();
    }
    *arr = shmat(shmid, (void *) 0, 0);
    if(pid != 0) 
    {
    *arr[i] = pid;
    }
    else 
    {
    pcid = *arr[i];
    break;
    }
}
if(pid != 0) 
{

    printf("Printing PID Array:\n");
    for(i =0; i < amount; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d\n", *arr[i]);
    }
}    
else 
{
    printf("My PID: %d\n",pcid);
}


}
```

Comment: Any process can get its own ID with `getpid()`. Is this what you need? If you want all children to get all other children's PIDs, that's a bit more complicated, you need to synchronize access to the shared memory which you don't seem to be doing.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. Let me give that a try.

Comment: Why are you using an array of pointers?

Comment: I thought that would give me the pointer for the array. Does it not?

Anyway, I got what I wanted thanks to n.m.

And the horrible code is because I'm taking this OS course in College, and our whole background is in Java, even the book is in Java, but the professor gives the lab in C/C++, which none of us are very familar with so we're all just scraping to get this done.

Comment: In C/C++, using an array in a value context automatically decays to a pointer to the array's first element. So declare `int arr[amount]`, and then when you refer to `arr` it will be a pointer.

Comment: And if you want to put something into the array, write `arr[i] = pid;`.

Answer (score 0):

you are using an array of pointers. And in line `*arr = shmat(shmid, (void *) 0, 0)` you assigned the shared memory access point to the first element of array. Now when you are using `*arr[i] = pid` it will go to the array `i+1` element where an unknown address stays and you try to put a value there. so you got segmentation fault.

Comment: use (*arr)[i] = pid statement instead of *arr[i] = pid. if you want to store pid values in shared memory segment.